# 2009 Honda Ridgeline power steering problem

Tags: honda, noise, power-steering, ridgeline

My 2009 Honda Ridgeline has been making weird whirring noises when turning . The noises have been coming from the power steering. Should I get the power steering fixed right away, or will it last a while longer even if it is making whirring noises. I don't want the power steering to stop working in the middle of the road so should I get it fixed right away or will it last.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the fluid level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a 1990 Honda Accord that had a very similar problem. It would often make a squealing/whirring noise when turning at intersections. The noise sounded like it was coming from the other side of the dashboard, near the power steering components.

I finally checked, and the power steering fluid was low. Filled it up to the correct level with the proper fluid, and the noise went away and never came back.

Comment: While this may work for the mean time, the thing to think about here is *why was it low in the first place?* ... The power steering is "basically" a closed system, meaning it doesn't use fluid. If you had to replace fluid, the car lost it somehow.

Comment: I had the dealership replace the fluid and it works with no whiring noise!